# How to replace very significant p values with 'p < 0.001'?

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, p-value

I have made a scatter plot with regression line and coefficients and obtained a very significant p. Is it possible to replace the p value automatically provided by R (1.6e-5) with 'p<0.001'.

Here is my code:

```
CorFrame2 <- data.frame(FFR2,iFR2)
ggplot(CorFrame2,aes(x=iFR2,y=FFR2))+
... +
stat_cor(aes(label = paste(..rr.label.., ..p.label.., sep = "~`,`~")),
       label.x = 0.20,label.y = 0.90,size=5)
```

Comment: It would be very helpful to have a working example instead of abbreviation (and no-data) code. Can you expand this, even if with a toy dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ggpubr::stat_cor` creates a string called `..p.label..` -- we can convert this to a number, evaluate whether it's <0.001, and use that to override the value in an `if_else` statement:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=wt,y=mpg))+
  geom_point() +
  ggpubr::stat_cor(
    aes(label = paste(..rr.label..,
                      if_else(readr::parse_number(..p.label..) < 0.001, 
                              "p<0.001", ..p.label..), sep = "~`,   `~")),
           label.x = 0.20,label.y = 0.90,size=5)
```

[image]

Same with `ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=wt,y=qsec))+`, which is less correlated:

[image]